# PostBack remove os items selecionados DropDownList múltiplo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Possuo um DropDownList (ddl1) múltiplo estático na minha página aspx. Ele possui 4 opções, na qual podem ser selecionadas de 0 à 4 opções.
Um outro DropDownList (ddl2) que também é estático no formulário possui o evento OnSelectedIndexChanged e quando este evento é disparado o dll1 perde as seleções múltiplas, mantendo apenas a primeira opção selecionada (ou nenhuma, caso o usuário não selecionar).

```
<!-- ddl1: -->

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelPesquisa" runat="server" CssClass="form-group">

<!--  [...] Alguns Campos de Busca [...] -->

    <asp:DropDownList ID="dpBuscaEtapasCapacitacao" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="BuscarQuestao" 
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chosen-select form-control" data- 
placeholder="Selecione as Etapas" multiple="multiple" TabIndex="4">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Nivelamento" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Capacitação EaD" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Capacitação Presencial" Value="2"> 
</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Atualização" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<!-- ddl2: -->

    <asp:DropDownList ID="dpBuscaPageSize" runat="server" CssClass="form- 
control" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="BuscaDados" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem Text=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="10"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

        </asp:Panel>

<!--  [...] Muito HTML depois [...] -->

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

O evento apenas atualiza a grid na tela, sem interação com os ddl's.

O que devo fazer para manter os items do ddl1 selecionados após o eventos serem disparados? Lembrando que o ddl não é carregado dinamicamente, então não tem como eu "chamar a função no postback" pois não há função.

Code Behind:

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        CarregaDados();
}

private void CarregaDados(){
    var lst = consulta_no_banco(" - sql_query - ");

    GridPrincipal.PageSize = int.Parse(dpBuscaPageSize.SelectedItem.Text);
    GridPrincipal.DataSource = lst;
    GridPrincipal.DataBind();
}
/*
    Esta função é chamada em todos os eventos dos Controls de filtro da tela.
    Cada TextChanged e SelectedItemChanged do filtro é direcionado para cá, mas 
    ainda não estou fazendo o filtro em sí.
*/
protected void BuscaDados(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CarregaDados();
}
```

Comment: Onde está o code behind?

Comment: O code behind está bem seco ainda. Ele só faz uma consulta no banco e joga numa GridView. A única parte que um dos ddls aparece no código é o seguinte:
`GridPrincipal.PageSize = int.Parse(dpBuscaPageSize.SelectedItem.Text)`

O PostBack não chama nada. O Carrega() é chamado apenas quando é !isPostBack, que por sua vez joga os dados na GridView e deu. Creio que não haja nenhuma relevância este caso. O change do ddl2 chama o Carrega() também.

Comment: mas tem o seu load e o evento que está disparando o postback...

Comment: Pronto. Não fiz os filtros ainda pois esse ddl não está se comportando como deveria, quando terminar a tela daí sim faço a parte funcional

Answer (score 0):

Precisa utilizar o UpdatePanel? Não consegue trocar para um Panel?

Outra coisa que podes verificar é se a ViewState está habilitada

Comment: Pior que preciso, não dá pra tirar ele não. Verifiquei e a ViewState está habilitada na página inteira.

Answer (score 0):

## Resolvido

Ao invés de um DropDownList, utilizei um select. No codeBehind há poucas diferenças mas são necessários alguns tratamentos a mais.
Não entendi exatamente o motivo mas mantive todos os demais elementos (inclusive UpdatePanels) e troquei apenas este. Os items pararam de ser resetados!

```
<select id="dpModulosLicenciados" runat="server" class="chosen-select form-control" data-placeholder="Selecione os Módulos" multiple="true" tabindex="4"></select>
```

Vida que segue minha gente. O importante é que funciona